# Serializing a DevExpress Panel Control

Tags: c#, serialization, devexpress

I have a program with a devexpress PanelControl which contains other data controls
(Text box, lists etc').
I need to save this panel (All the data that the user entered) to
my DB to display it later.
I tried to serialize the PanelControl using BinaryFormatter but the class
is not serializable..
Any idea how I can serialize the entire panel?
I hate having
to access each Text field of every control and append it to a file..
It just seems wrong \=

Comment: Storing your UI directly in the database? This just seems wrong. What happens when you upgrade your DevExpress DLL and the stream format changes? Don't you have a set of data access classes in between?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do not serialize your GUI controls for this purpose.  Perhaps, it is better to adjust bindings and bind your editors to some data?  In this case, you will have to serialize your DataSource, not the GUI, and this looks like a much more better solution...